# UILabels not showing in subclass of UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a custom view (subclass of UIView) in which I want to show a UIImageView and several UILabels. The imageView comes asynchronously from FaceBook and the labels get their text from specific methods. The issue is that even though the imageView is rendered successfully when it arrives the labels are not shown.
Let me show you the code

```
@interface CustomView : UIView {

    UIImageView *imageView;
    UILabel *lbl1;
    UILabel *lbl2;
    UILabel *lbl3;
    UILabel *lbl4;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *lbl1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *lbl2;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *lbl3;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *lbl4;
```

And the implementation is as follows:

```
@implementation CustomView

@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize lbl1;
@synthesize lbl2;
@synthesize lbl3;
@synthesize lbl4;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        self.lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 356, 98, 13)];
        self.lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:self.lbl1];

        self.lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 356, 50, 13)];
        self.lbl2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:self.lbl2];

        self.lbl3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 374, 92, 13)];
        self.lbl3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:self.lbl3];

        self.lbl4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 374, 49, 13)];
        self.lbl4.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:self.lbl4];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Please note that label rectangles are hardcoded for convenience and do not match.
A sample for the method to set label text is the following:

```
- (void)showLbl1:(NSString *)str withFont:(UIFont *)font andColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    self.lbl1.font = font;
    self.lbl1.textColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
    [self.lbl1 setText:str];
}
```

The image is delivered with a method that runs by performSelectorInBackground and drawn with a method that runs by performSelectorOnMainThread.
Finally, the whole view is added by addSubView in the superView.

Thanx in advance

Comment: add your label as subview of view like this [self.view addSubview:self.lbl4];

Comment: Are the showLbl1 and such methods being called at all?

Comment: @ozzotto:can u get me?if any queries ask?

Comment: 'self' is subclass of UIView so self.view doesn't exist. perhaps you mean [superview.view addSubview:lbl1] ?

Comment: @Prajan, it looks like this is just a UIView and not a UIViewController, so 'self' should be correct and not 'self.view'

Comment: @ozzotto:why u use that method?simply u give myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size: 14.0]; in ur designated initializer method itself.

Comment: @ozzotto:then u simply give your view name(UIView)[yourviewname addsubview:lbl];

Comment: @Prajan:'show' method is CustomView's method and i am using it to set dynamically text, font and textColor for each label

Comment: Try to add subview in `showLbl...` method. Are they displayed?

Comment: @Nekto: That didn't work either! Finally I managed to make it work by adding all elements in the UIViewController and performing whole functionality there (self.view addSubView) even though I don't like much this implementation. Thx everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try drawing the labels borders and see where they are ... Also check the uber leak you have there, you have an alloc init and never release the labels and also using the setter, so you are doing a double alloc init.